# Elastic privilege to create index only

Tags: elasticsearch, permissions, roles

Is there a role privilege in elasticsearch giving only new index creation rights?

Also, is there a way to automatically give write and/or read privileges on an index to the user who created it?

Answer (score 0):

To give a role the index creation rights, add the index privilege `"*": ["create_index"]`.

To automaticaly give rights on an index to its creator you can add an index privilege with a pattern `"project-*": ["create_index", "read"]"`

The index 'project-log' will be readable by its creator.